# How to display the content of a file on a screen using kivy and python?

Tags: python, android, kivy, display, kivymd

**This is the code in python for reading the particular file.**

class Display2(Screen):

```
def data_even(self):
    w_f = "abc.docs"
    try:
        with open(f"{w_f}") as w:
            f = w.readlines()
           
            self.ids.display.text = str(f)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        self.ids.display.text = "Not found, Sorry, the user has no data entered yet."
```

**In KIVY**

KV= '''
:

```
name: "Display2" 
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Label:
        id: display
        text: "I will be displaying your data"
        color: "#1e272e"
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.1}
            id:data
            text: "Show Data"
            on_press: root.data_even()

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.1}
            text: "Close"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Evening"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

'''

When I am trying to run this above code snippet I am not able to see the text which is present in the file instead only a black colored label is coming. I hope I explained myself clear. Thanks!!

**Please note this is not the full code only some snippets of the program**

Comment: Were you able to display anything meaningful at all with Kivy? Even following a tutorial step by step? Did you try to change the tutorial code gradually until it matches your example? If you do that, does it help you find the problem?

Comment: Separately: what colour do you think the label should be? Is there some part of your code that is supposed to choose that colour? Where? I assume you expect `"#1e272e"` to specify the colour for the text. What do you think that colour should look like? Do you think it will stand out against a black background?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel what I was able to display was just a strip of black color, the color of the text ie "#1e272e" is a kind of black shade. The background I have is white so this color should work.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that it's putting the text on top of the strip, such that it isn't noticeable?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Since I wanted to display the text but not the strip I wasn't able to check why the strip was coming. And it wasn't giving any kind of error too. I tried the exceptional case where it displays the "file is not found" that is getting displayed on the screen as expected but not the file content.

Comment: What if you try explicitly specifying a colour for the button?

Comment: But its a label right ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I tried changing the color of the label to yellow still I am getting the same old black strip.

Comment: I mean, I don't actually know anything about Kivy; but I see something in your .kv file that says `MDFillRoundFlatButton`, and seems like it's intended to describe part of what gets drawn, and doesn't seem to say anything about the colour to use.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It by default takes the color of the button as blue and I don't think this is where the problem is cuzz the buttons are working fine..

Answer (score 0):

**How to display the content of a file on a screen using kivy and python ?**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

def get_text(file_path):
    try:
        with open(f"{file_path}") as w:
            f = w.readlines()
        return str(f)
    except:
        return "Not found, Sorry, the user has no data entered yet."

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text=get_text("abc.txt"), color="#ffc100")

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I am giving the file path as abc.docs it says this "..
 BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 274:
 ...
"

Comment: Check how to read the `.docs` with python and the data that you have on it, try to write only `"Hello World !`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question!!!

I replaced the label with texinput and now the program is working fine.

**This is the code in python for reading the particular file.**

class Display2(Screen):

def data_even(self):
w_f = "abc.docs"
try:
with open(f"{w_f}") as w:
f = w.readlines()

```
        self.ids.display.text = str(f)

except FileNotFoundError:
    self.ids.display.text = "Not found, Sorry, the user has no data entered yet."
```

**In KIVY**

KV= ''' :

name: "Display2"

GridLayout:

```
cols: 1
**TextInput:**
    id: display
    text: "I will be displaying your data"
    color: "#1e272e"
MDFloatLayout:
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.1}
        id:data
        text: "Show Data"
        on_press: root.data_even()

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.1}
        text: "Close"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "Evening"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```